# Trying to launch Atom in Git bash

Tags: atom-editor, git-bash

I create an alias

```
$ echo 'alias atom="C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\atom\atom.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

[I open bashrc file with VI editor and it shows the alias.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clp9f.png)
But when I tried to use the alias it gives me the folowing error

```
$ atom start.txt
bash: C:UsersMyUserAppDataLocalatomatom.exe: command not found
$ atom
bash: C:UsersmyUserAppDataLocalatomatom.exe: command not found
```

Comment: Based on the error message and the fact that you used double quotes, you may need to double each \ . So replace each  \ by  \\ or by /

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the alias to use the `cd` command to navigate to the location with the `.exe`, and then use `./` to execute the `.exe`.

Here is an example that I made in Cygwin to execute Sublime Text with an alias `sublime`.

`alias sublime="cd /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/ && ./sublime_text.exe"`

With Git Bash I think you can just do `cd /c/... && ./program.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it using an expecific version of atom (in my case "app-1.28.2"):

`alias atom="/c/Users/Usuario/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.28.2/atom.exe"`